# java - JTextArea expands dynamically (undesired)

Tags: java, jtextarea, boxlayout

Something strange occured. I have a text area and a button. When I type text into the area, the button starts moving! Please see attached code. I tried adding more layers of panels and setting component alignments, but it still happens.

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
...
public MyFrame() {
    super("example");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(panel);

    JTextArea _textArea = new JTextArea();
    _textArea.setSize(800, 600);
    panel.add(_textArea);

    JButton btn = new JButton("Send");
    panel.add(btn);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1000, 800);
    setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

whats the mystery all about?  how does one component affects the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BoxLayout` is a lot more complicated than `BorderLayout`, which is what you need. BorderLayout uses general directions like `NORTH`, `EAST`, `SOUTH`, and `WEST`, which is very simple. Here's the easy way to get what you're looking for:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    //...
    public MyFrame() {
        super("Example");   
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setSize(800, 600);
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Send");
        add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1000, 800); 
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

A lot shorter too.

Comment: does that makes the box layout redundant?

Comment: @tamir I just edited my post. Please look at it now, and yes, that's why I removed the `BoxLayout` altogether.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
_textArea.setSize(800, 600);
```

is ignored, because the LayoutManager of a component’s parent decides what the size will be.  In your case, that LayoutManager is your BoxLayout.

LayoutManagers determine the positions and sizes of the components they manage.  That’s their job.  They use each component’s minimum size, preferred size, and maximum size to decide the actual size.  If you want to know the exact algorithm, read [BoxLayout’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html).

Generally, you set a JTextArea’s preferred size by setting its rows and columns:

```
JTextArea _textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
```

JTextArea is designed to be placed in a JScrollPane.  If you don’t put it in a JScrollPane, it may not act as you expect, especially if the user types more text than can fit in it:

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(_textArea));
```

You should probably read through [JTextArea’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) to understand it better.

Comment: does that explain the effect of the typing on the button?

Comment: @tamir Yes.  A JTextArea’s preferred size depends on the text in it, unless you set the rows and columns.